# Stanford CoreNLP Universal Dependencie

Tags: stanford-nlp

Which code properties I need use to get the result as in online parse http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp:

Sentence: Wonderful Doctor. I cant say enough good things about him.
Online parse:

compound(Doctor-2, Wonderful-1)
root(ROOT-0, Doctor-2)

nsubj(say-3, I-1)
advmod(say-3, cant-2)
root(ROOT-0, say-3)
advmod(good-5, enough-4)
amod(things-6, good-5)
dobj(say-3, things-6)
case(him-8, about-7)
nmod(things-6, him-8)

Coding:
I am using Stanford coreNLP 3.5.2. I tried several properties as below, but I Am getting different results.

```
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, depparse");
//props.put("ner.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/ner/english.all.3class.distsim.crf.ser.gz");
// props.put("annotators", "tokenize, ssplit, pos, lemma, ner, depparse", "parse","sentiment, dcoref");
//props.put("parse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz");
        //props.put("parse.model","edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishPCFG.ser.gz");
//props.put("tokenize.options", "ptb3Escaping=false");
//props.put("parse.maxlen", "10000");
//props.put("ner.applyNumericClassifiers", "true");
//props.put("depparse.model", "edu/stanford/nlp/models/parser/nndep/english_SD.gz");
//props.put("depparse.extradependencies", "ref_only_uncollapsed");
        props.put("depparse.extradependencies", "MAXIMAL");
//props.put("depparse.originalDependencies", false);
props.put("parse.originalDependencies", false);
```

Comment: The parser should give you universal dependencies by default in CoreNLP 3.5.2. Is it not?

Comment: Hi Gabor, The documentation explains put properties "depparse.originalDependencies" or "parse.originalDependencies as false but when I use online parse results are different .

Comment: The online parser is using an older version, so it doesn't match 3.5.2 right now